# Jmeter Response data:java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Tags: java, jmeter

[the whole test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH3xy.png)

[result of debug postpropossor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZsDW.png)

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ormLJ.png)

[httprequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcnfg.png)
it happend after about 20 seconds,with not too much threads about 50.what's the problem with the error?

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:99)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1814)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:500)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.readResponse(HTTPJavaImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:570)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[java.io.IOException: Premature EOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8LGA.png)

Comment: The problem with the error is that it is thrown. There might be something wrong with the file you're trying to handle. is there (for instance) an empty line after the contents?

Comment: You need to provide more details, how does ur test plan look like

Comment: @pvpkiran thank you for the reply. I've added more details :)

Comment: do you have any other config in your test plan? like json extractor or csv data set config or something?

Comment: @pvpkiran no.The whole plan only has one http request and the listeners.

Comment: try adding a debug post processor and see where exactly is it going wrong? can you show your listneres

Comment: @pvpkiran  I've pasted the plan and the result of debugPP. It has a http GET request, an assertion find 'code:succcess' for the reponse,  a result tree and a report. Thank you so much:)

Comment: what do u have in your assertion?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @pvpkiran have 'code:succcess' must in response in my assertion

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it indicates the problem with the [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) itself, i.e. you're receiving a response in [chunked format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#Chunked_encoding) and not all response parts could be downloaded.

1. Inspect your application logs for any suspicious entries
2. Make sure that the system under test has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap, etc. - this could be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) or [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon#sshmon-samples-collector-)
3. Make sure your HTTP Request configuration exactly matches the request which is being sent by the real browser, i.e. you might need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send all the headers which real browser is sending.

---

If you're absolutely sure that the problem is not on your SUT end you can try switching "Implementation" for your HTTP Request samplers to `HTTPClient4`, this could be done at "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler

[image: JMeter HTTPClient Imelementation]